# C# Check If List Contains Similiar Strings Using LINQ

Tags: c#, list, linq

So I have a list that looks something like the following:

```
{"Apples Oranges Canada", "Fruit Apples US", "Food Something US", "Another Word Japan"}
```

How can I count how many times each country is mentioned in the list and return an integer? So Canada is mentioned once (1), US is mentioned twice (2) and Japan is mentioned once (1).

Please note that the country will always be the last word in the list's element and I **do not** know what specific countries are in the list.

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried? If you haven't tried anything yet, I'd start with figuring out how to isolate the last word in each string.

Comment: " the country will always be the last word"...famous last words.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Extract* countries, and `GroupBy` by them:

```
 string[] source = new string[] {
   "Apples Oranges Canada", "Fruit Apples US", "Food Something US", "Another Word Japan"};

 var result = source
   .GroupBy(item => item.Substring(item.LastIndexOf(' ') + 1))
   .OrderBy(chunk => chunk.Key)
   .Select(chunk => $"{chunk.Key,-8} appears {chunk.Count()} times");

Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

Outcome:

```
Canada   appears 1 times
Japan    appears 1 times
US       appears 2 times
```

Comment: Substring, nice touch.

Answer (score 0):

You could split each element by spaces, then group by the last token and count the number of occurrences:

```
var data = new[] { "Apples Oranges Canada", "Fruit Apples US", "Food Something US", "Another Word Japan" };
var result = data.GroupBy(x =>
{
    var tokens = x.Split(' ');
    var country = tokens[tokens.Length - 1];
    return country;
})
.Select(g => new
{
    Country = g.Key,
    Count = g.Count(),
});

foreach (var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Country: {0}, Count: {1}", item.Country, item.Count);
}
```

Which will print:

```
Country: Canada, Count: 1
Country: US, Count: 2
Country: Japan, Count:
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this  (Try in Linqpad)

```
var data = new[] { "Apples Oranges Canada", "Fruit Apples US", "Food Something US", "Another Word YASH" };
var result = data.GroupBy(x => x.Split(' ').LastOrDefault(),(a, b) => new { Country = a, Count = b.Count()});
result.Dump()
```